# MongoDB: Create another collection from sub-array? (many-to-many relationship)

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have 'film' objects like the one below in my collection. Films have many actors, and actors belong to many films. Many-to-many.

How do I create another collection that consists of the unique 'actor' elements? Remember, some actors will be listed in more than one film.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4edcffa5f320646bc8bd76b4"),
    "directed_by" : [
        "John Gilling"
    ],
    "forbid:genre" : null,
    "genre" : [ ],
    "guid" : "#9202a8c04000641f8000000000b02e5d",
    "id" : "/en/pirates_of_blood_river",
    "initial_release_date" : "1962",
    "name" : "Pirates of Blood River",
    "starring" : [
        {
            "actor" : {
                "guid" : "#9202a8c04000641f800000000006823e",
                "id" : "/en/christopher_lee",
                "name" : "Christopher Lee",
                "lc_name" : "christopher lee"
            }
        },
        {
            "actor" : {
                "guid" : "#9202a8c04000641f80000000001de22e",
                "id" : "/en/oliver_reed",
                "name" : "Oliver Reed",
                "lc_name" : "oliver reed"
            }
        },
        {
            "actor" : {
                "guid" : "#9202a8c04000641f80000000003b41da",
                "id" : "/en/glenn_corbett",
                "name" : "Glenn Corbett",
                "lc_name" : "glenn corbett"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: so you want to use your current mongo db to spin off and create a separate actor collection? It seems like this would be best done through a function you create in which ever language you're using to interact with mongo, or through js functions on mongo.

Comment: @Frederico that's pretty much it, yes. The main reason I want to even bother creating a separate collection is because of Mongo's current inability to return the nested array elements that my query matches. For example, if I want to query my current film collection for all actors named "Johnny", while I could get all the film documents returned that have actors named Johnny in them, I can't get JUST the actor info for the element that matches, ie: 'Johnny Depp', 'Johnny Carson', etc. This functionality is supposed to be coming in Mongo v2.1.1 (see: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-828 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in the client app, but also via aggregation in mongodb - for example, you can run a mapreduce job with an output collection.  In the map step, given a film document, you can emit key value pairs of ( actor.guid, { [other actor details] } ), and in the reduce step just return a single set of details (you could also count the number of films the actor was in at this point, if you wanted).

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce has more info on the syntax.